# How to mirror traffic across namespaces with istio?

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I am trying to mirror traffic to two copies of the same service in different namespaces. I can access both services by curling their FQDN from a pod running in the default namespace but when i apply the following virtual service nothing gets mirrored. What am i doing wrong?

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: testservice-virtual-service
spec:
  hosts:
  - testservice.default.svc.cluster.local
  gateways:
  - istio-system/my-gateway
  http:
  - route:
    - destination:
        host: testservice.default.svc.cluster.local
      weight: 100
    mirror:
        host: testservice.staging.svc.cluster.local
    mirrorPercentage:
        value: 100.0
```

**EDIT** - I have tried adding just the service from the default namespace using the FQDN to the hosts field as well as adding both the default and staging namespace services using the FQDN and still do not see any traffic being mirrored to the staging service.

Comment: your hosts field needs to be fqdn?

Comment: I added an edit to the question but i have tried this and i still get no mirrored traffic

Comment: Could you remove the field `mirrorPercentage` and test it again? You can use the value field under the `mirrorPercentage` field to mirror a fraction of the traffic, instead of mirroring all requests. If this field is absent, all traffic will be mirrored. See also this doc: https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/mirroring/

Comment: I have removed the mirrorPercentage and still get no traffic to the staging service. I implemented this following the doc you linked.  

a few questions:  
1.  What should the destinationRule look like for this because there is no labels or anything like that but simply the same service in 2 namespaces. does it even need to exist?            
2. should the virtual service exist in both or only one namespace?           
3.  has anyone else succesfully mirrored traffic between namespaces? I cant find a single example of this on the web.

Comment: SOLVED - I was doing something extremely stupid and did not have istio enabled in the default namespace. thanks to all for trying to help

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have posted community wiki answer for better visibility.

As OP has mentioned in the comment, the problem is resolved:

> I was doing something extremely stupid and did not have istio enabled in the default namespace.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue while following the [istio official document](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/mirroring/).
I resolved it by adding the port for the host

```
mirror:
  host: <service_name>.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local
  port: 80
mirrorPercentage:
  value: 100
```

Comment: It also doesn't need to specify the **subset** in destinationrule